# How to Use onOpen Trigger Script to Change Google Sheet Behavior?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

On the advice of someone below, I am editing this post:

My initial goal is that when my Google sheet is opened, and every time it is opened, I would like the values of several Data Validation dropdown menus, currently located in Cells A10, A15, and A20, to be set to the option of "Select" -- which is a word in the validation range, along with 2 other text values.

I have been informed that this needs to be declared at a global scope -- but I am a complete script novice and, frankly, have no idea as to how to make this work.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A10').setValue('Select');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A15').setValue('Select');
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A20').setValue('Select');
```

Comment: are you aware that your users need to install this script too otherwise nothing will happen for them, right?

Comment: Good question.  I had thought that if the Google Sheet lived in my G Suite account, and I gave permission for two or threes users to access the Sheet via Share permissions, that it would automatically run along with the Sheet.  Am I mistaken?

Comment: pretty much yes. they need to install it unless you give them your acc :)

Comment: Well, if true, that is a deal-killer -- as my users will never remember to manually run the script prior to working with the sheet.

Comment: they would need to just authorize it for themselves just once (first time they use the sheet)

Comment: Oh.  That's a bit different.  I can definitely help them to do that once -- as long as it is persistent and does not need to happen again.

Comment: I rolled back the question to a previous revision because follow-up questions should be posted as new question, not as an edit of an already answered question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note for new readers:

> The original code on the question was this
>
> ```
>  //When the sheet is opened, the contents of Cell A2 are cleared and the values in the Data Validation dropdown menus in Cells A10, A15, and A20 are set to the default "Select"
>
>
> function myFunction() {
>   function onOpen() {
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A2').clearContent();   
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A10').setValue('Select');
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A15').setValue('Select');
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A20').setValue('Select');
> }
>
> //When the contents of Cell A2 are edited (changed), the values in the Data Validation dropdown menus in Cells A10, A15, and A20 are set to the default "Select"
>
>
> function onEdit(e) {
>   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
>   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
>   var cell = sheet.getRange('A2')
>   var cellContent = cell.getValue()
>
>   if(cellContent === (edit) {
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A10').setValue('Select');
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A15').setValue('Select');
>     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A20').setValue('Select');
>
>
>   }
> }
> ```

Simple triggers should not be declared as local functions of another function, they should be declared at the global scope.

In other words, don't put `onOpen` and `onEdit` inside of `myFunction`.

---

A function on the global scope in a Google Apps Script script looks like this:

[image]

NOTE: Only one code line is included inside `onOpen` code block `{}` for simplicity. It could have any number of code lines that takes no more than 30 seconds to execute.

---

By the other hand simple triggers has several limitations so maybe instead of simple triggers you should consider to use installable triggers. To learn about Google Apps Script triggers please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Also, you should bear in mind the real-time collaboration features of Google Sheets. If one user has opened the spreadsheet and another user open the same spreadsheet, the `onOpen`, simple and installable triggers, will be triggered and could change what the first user already edited.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I am really lost.  Would it be possible for you to edit my supplied script so that it accomplishes my goals?  If so, I would be very grateful.  Thank you.

Comment: @blafarm I'm sorry but don't think that I will do that in first place because I don't understand your use case (the information is incomplete)  and in second place because while there are many answers that fix the OP code, this site isn't a place to request other write script on their behalf. Have you already read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets and https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/custom-functions?

Comment: I have reviewed those links -- thank you.  However, I am a complete novice and I am clearly out of my depth.  I was only hoping for someone to point out why my existing script was not working.  I can't be the only beginner starting from scratch and looking for a helping hand.  At the same time, I do understand why you are unwilling to help.  A sincere thanks the links -- they interesting and probably useful -- but I have a bigger picture lack of understanding.  I will wait to see if someone else is kind enough to chime in.

Comment: @blafarm Regarding writing scripts maybe you should take some steps back and start with something simpler and if that doesn't work post a new question.

Comment: Another alternative is to edit your question by yourself to limit it to one trigger.

Comment: Post has been revised.

Comment: @blafarm I added a image to may answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt reply and excellent assistance.  Should I post a follow-up question here -- or in another thread?

Comment: I updated my original post with the follow-up question.  Thank you.

Comment: @blafarm follow-up questions should be posted as new questions.

Answer (score 3):

After some testing I was able to make it work. As Ruben said, onOpen, onEdit cannot be inside any other function. These specify already an action so when an action of onOpen or onEdit the script will be running automatically when the spreadsheet is opened or edited.

You can check more information about Apps Script Triggers https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers but in this specific case onEdit will run every time any cell is updated unless you specify the cell you want to run the script by using Event Objects for more information check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events.

For this specific scenario since you want the script to run when the cell is updated you have to check if that cell is being updated by using e.range.getA1Notation() the getA1Notation() returns the range in A1 notation for more information check https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation() there is an example that will make you understand the following script.

```
    function onOpen(e){

  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet();  
  sheet.getRange("A2:A2").clearContent();
  sheet.getRange("A10:A10").setValue("Select");
  sheet.getRange("A15:A15").setValue("Select");
  sheet.getRange("A20:A20").setValue("Select");
}



function onEdit(e){

  var app = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = app.getActiveSheet();
  var A2 = sheet.getRange("A2:A2");

  console.log(e.range.getA1Notation());
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === "A2"){

    console.log("A2 Updated");
    sheet.getRange("A10:A10").setValue('Select');
  sheet.getRange("A15:A15").setValue('Select');
  sheet.getRange("A20:A20").setValue('Select');

  } 
}
```

the onOpen function will be running every time the spreadsheet is opened, and the onEdit function will be executed every time the cell "A2" changes its value. Basically you are checking if the range with A1 Notation is equals to "A2" then it will run the code within the if statement, otherwise the function will be executed but will take no action since the cell A2 is still without any change. By doing this I am not sure if there is a limit of this kind of executions but that is something you can investigate further, I don't think it will affect since this should be running on the client side not on a server side.

I hope that helps, greetings.

Comment: Thank you very much Mario R.  It works perfectly.  Cheers.  Looks like there can only be one answer, sorry that I cannot mark both your answers.

Comment: You are welcome, no worries. It was a pleasure to help. Greetings.